# Different types of data in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to import data from a file into an array, with 2 columns, with %f type and %d type respectively.
I tried:

```
T=textscan(file,'%f %d',n);
T=cell2mat(T);
```

But cell2mat is not compatible with different types.
Is there a workaround ?

Comment: What about converting the content to the same datatype first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of function for reading files. It depends on data types, for example.
One of them you can use:

```
fileID = fopen('yourfile.txt','r');

formatSpec = '%f %d';
sizeA = [2 Inf];

A = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,sizeA)
fclose(fileID);

A = A';
```